# Forward my http requests from my ip to another server

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, firewall, iptables

I need to forward any http request from my old server IP to my new IP.

I migrated servers and there are a few domains that have a high TTL and I could not update. Is it possible to take all HTTP requests from one server running centos/whm/php/apache 2+ and forward them to the new ip?

Since I have hundreds of domains I'd prefer a solution that involves running an app on the linux box that will push requests automatically to the new box.

Thoughts?

I've tried using IP tables and forwarding all incoming connections using the preroute chain, but it seems like this only works for forwarding to internal IP addresses, and the new IP is external.

Comment: I think you probably forwarded the *packets* rather than the connections (through NAT). Forwarding the *connections* should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to set up `nginx` on your old IP.
And your should alter its config to make it act as a reverse proxy, something like this:

```
server {
        listen   80 default;
        server_name  localhost;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;

        location / {
                proxy_pass         http://your_new_ip_here:80/;
                proxy_redirect     off;
                proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $remote_addr;

                client_max_body_size       10m;
                client_body_buffer_size    128k;

                proxy_connect_timeout      90;
                proxy_send_timeout         180;
                proxy_read_timeout         180;

                charset utf-8;
        }
}
```

Comment: Where do I put this? I put it in the config but it said unknown directive server

Comment: Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "server" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:13

Comment: All good, worked it out ... had to edit /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf. Thanks, this worked perfectly!

Comment: This is just an excerpt, the full config should have more lines, let me paste you a full example somewhere

Comment: Oh I see. Great!