# Forwarding all HTTP/HTTPS from server to another server

Tags: reverse-proxy, https, http, nat

I need to forward all traffic(HTTP/HTTPs) to my server (Digital ocean) to a new server (AWS load balancer) basically the solution is to use nginx as this questions: [Forward my http requests from my ip to another server](https://serverfault.com/questions/330638/forward-my-http-requests-from-my-ip-to-another-server)

But what I am thinking about, is it doable to forward the traffic using NAT or something else like forwarding on network layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forwarding http and https traffic at the network layer is of course an option but with double NAT you will lose the source IP-address of the traffic.

If you had intended to use an AWS load balancing scheme based on IP-address , be aware that all your traffic will appear to originate from your Digital Ocean IP and probably no load balancing will occur.

Forwarding on the application layer (with a reverse proxy ) offers you the option to for example add a header to requests with the original IP-address (`X-Forwarded-For: IP-address` is a common one) which in turn allows you to use that information to do something useful on the new server or the load balancer.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do it at the network layer, following something [like this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-forward-ports-through-a-linux-gateway-with-iptables).

However, you're just complicating things at a deeper level of the OSI model than you really need to, and could run into issues with the TCP handshake and/or getting the correct IP in your logs at the destination.

Unless there is some compelling reason not to, it's probably better to just use nginx to forward all packets. Assuming you have DNS as well and you're just moving where that DNS resolves to, setup nginx to forward, then update your DNS and once you know it has aged out correctly, shut down nginx and remove it (again, assuming you have DNS and that you're moving to a different location to serve traffic).

Comment: dear @tilleyc please provide in your question a example and only a reference to the site